# Django: Permissions granted to auth user but not there in view / template?

Tags: django, authorization

In my Django project and using django.contrib.auth, I have granted a bunch of permissions for my new app to a particular user:

[image: User permissions]

However, in my view, `request.user.has_perm('whwn.can_change_situation')` is `False` and in my template, `{% if perms.whwn.can_change_situation %}` is also not working. I have also tried making a group with these permissions and putting the user in the group, but that didn't work.

The permissions do work fine for a SuperUser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you logout and then login the user after you made the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did, no luck. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Are the permissions reflected at the admin? What does [`{{ perms }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#users) output in the template?

Comment: I applied the permissions through the admin interface and they do show up there as I would expect (the screenshot is from the admin interface). `{{perms}}` in the template shows `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x98d0f6c>`. I can't loop over it, get a template error `PermWrapper is not iterable`.

Comment: You can only iterate over it in 1.5, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `request.user.has_perm('whwn.change_situation')` as explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).